# Login Authentication in react and laravel not logging

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, react-router

I am new to react and react router and i am trying to make authentication with help of laravel react and react router. The page is redirecting to desired destination as the url changes when submit button is hit but there seems to be error which i cant figure out.  When i manually reload the page the component seems to render but when submit button is clicked / form is submitted the react throws below error.

**Error In Console**

```
Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state. app.js:39442:7
The above error occurred in the <LoginPage> component:
    in LoginPage (created by Route)
    in Route (created by withRouter(LoginPage))
    in withRouter(LoginPage) (created by Route)
    in Route (created by RouterComponent)
    in Switch (created by RouterComponent)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (created by RouterComponent)
    in RouterComponent
    in Provider

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Error: LoginPage(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null. app.js:38991:15
Source map error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
Resource URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js
Source Map URL: popper.js.map[Learn More]
```

**Login Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import '../../../public/admin/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import '../../../public/admin/css/themify-icons.css';
import '../../../public/admin/css/styles.css';
import { withRouter, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
class LoginPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            token: '',
            loggingIn: false,
            error: []
        }
        this.changeVal = this.changeVal.bind(this);
        this.login = this.login.bind(this);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            token: document.getElementById("csrf-token").getAttribute("content")
        })
    }
    changeVal(e) {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
    }
    login(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let arr = {
            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password,
            token: this.state.token
        };
        let route = e.target.getAttribute('action');
        axios.post(route, arr).then(response => {
            localStorage.setItem('userId', response.data[0].id);
            localStorage.setItem('loggedIn', "true");
            this.props.history.push('/admin/dashboard');
        }).catch(error => {
            if(localStorage.getItem('userId') !== null) return localStorage.removeItem('userId');
            if(localStorage.getItem('loggedIn') !== null) return localStorage.removeItem('loggedIn');
            console.log(response.error);
        })
    }
    render() {
        if ((localStorage.getItem('loggedIn') === "true")) return this.props.history.push('/admin/dashboard');
        return (
            <div className="login-area">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="login-box ptb--100">
                        <form method="POST" onSubmit={this.login} action="/api/login">
                            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value={this.state.token} />
                            <div className="login-form-head">
                                <h4>Sign In</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div className="login-form-body">

                                <div className="form-gp">
                                    {
                                        /*     this.props.errors.map(item => {
                                            return (
                                                <span key={item} className="text-danger d-block" role="alert">
                                                    <strong>{item}</strong>
                                                </span>
                                            )
                                        }) */
                                    }
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-gp">
                                    <input id="email" type="email" className={"form-control "} name="email" autoFocus value={this.state.email} onChange={this.changeVal} />
                                    <i className="ti-email"></i>
                                </div>

                                <div className="form-gp">
                                    <input id="password" type="password" className={"form-control"} name="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.changeVal} />
                                    <i className="ti-lock"></i>
                                </div>

                                <div className="form-gp">
                                    <a href="/password/reset">Forgot Password?</a>
                                </div>
                                <div className="submit-btn-area">
                                    <button id="form_submit" type="submit" >{(this.props.loggedIn) ? "Submit Form" : "Please fill form"}  <i className="ti-arrow-right"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default (withRouter(LoginPage));
```

**Router Component**

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import IndexPage from './components/IndexPage';
import ContactPage from './components/ContactPage';
import CmsPage from './components/CmsPage';
import ErrorPage from './components/ErrorPage';
import ThanksPage from './components/ThanksPage';
import LoginPage from './components/LoginPage';
import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard';
import withRoot from './Root';
import {PrivateRoute} from './layouts/helpers';
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Route,Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
class RouterComponent extends Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <Router basename={'/'}>
                <Switch> 
                    <Route path="/" exact component={withRoot(IndexPage)} />
                    <Route path="/contact" exact component={withRoot(ContactPage)} />
                    <Route path="/thanks" exact component={withRoot(ThanksPage)} />
                    <Route path="/page/:id" exact component={withRoot(CmsPage)} />
                    <Route path="/page/:id/subpage/:subId" exact component={withRoot(CmsPage)} />
                    <Route path="/admin/login" exact component={LoginPage} />
                    <PrivateRoute authed={(localStorage.getItem('loggedIn') === "true")} path='/admin/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
                    <Route component={ErrorPage} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}
export default RouterComponent;
```

**Protected Route**

```
export function PrivateRoute ({component: Component, authed, ...rest}) {
    return (
      <Route exact
        {...rest}
        render={(props) => authed === true
          ? <Component {...props} />
          : <Redirect to={{pathname: '/admin/login', state: {from: props.location}}} />}
      />
    )
  }
```

**Dashboard or where the login redirects**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
class Dashboard extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      token:'',
      userId: localStorage.getItem('userId'),
      loggedIn: (localStorage.getItem('loggedIn') === "true")
    }
    this.logout = this.logout.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
      this.setState({
          token: document.getElementById("csrf-token").getAttribute("content")
      })
  }
  logout(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let route = e.target.getAttribute("action");
    let arr = {
      token : this.state.token
    }
    axios.post(route,arr).then(response => {
      localStorage.removeItem('loggedIn');
      localStorage.removeItem('userId');
      this.props.history.push('/admin/login');
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    })
    console.log("route ->" + route);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {localStorage.getItem('userId')}
        <form action="/api/logout" className="d-inline-block" method="post" onSubmit={this.logout}>
          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value={this.state.token} />
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Logout</button>
        </form>
      </>
    )
  }
}
export default (withRouter(Dashboard));
```

**Any code change or practices implementation is appreciated**

Comment: Please, add the error as a text, not as an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to solve this problem.

1.First remove the following logic from the render in login component

```
if ((localStorage.getItem('loggedIn') === "true")) return this.props.history.push('/admin/dashboard');
```

2.Add a lifecycle method in login component

```
  componentDidUpdate(){
   if ((localStorage.getItem('loggedIn') === "true")) 
    return this.props.history.push('/admin/dashboard');
}
```

It is because the render in React should be pure. But in your login Component, you want to redirect to dashboard while it was still trying to render the current component.This sort of action is generally not allowed. The best way to redirect users to dashboard if they are logged in is to add a componentDidUpdate.

A Note:
React already published 16.8 you can use hook instead of class component.If you use hook, you can do it like this:

```
    useEffect(()=>{
if(localStorage.getItem('loggedIn')&&localStorage.getItem('loggedIn')==='true){
props.history.push('/admin/dashboard')
}
})
```

Hope this solves your problem.
Thanks.

Comment: I get this error

Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Comment: did you use this.setState in componentDidupdate?Doing this will result in an unlimited updating this component.